# Python Test Case Failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve a simple python code it run successfully but it fails all the test cases. Can anyone help what mistake I'm doing.

```
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    first_name = 'Ross'
    last_name = 'Taylor'
    
    print(f'Hello {first_name} {last_name} ! You are welcome.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_name = input()
    last_name = input()
    print_full_name(first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: What test cases? We can see what `print_full_name` *does*, but not what it is *expected* to do.

Comment: Is it supposed to *return* a string instead of writing it to standard output?

Comment: Is it supposed to use the given `first_name` and `last_name` arguments instead of always using "Ross" and "Taylor"?

Comment: Note, though, that you are ignoring the arguments to `print_full_name` and always printing the same hard-coded string, `Hello Ross Taylor ! You are welcome.'`

Comment: It's complete code

Comment: Could you provide several test cases and show what it does instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supplied does not contain a test so the question is a little confusing.

If you are asking why your inputs do not end up in the print statement.

The following is the answer:

Your method parameters are overridden inside the method by the following lines, this is referred to as hard coding the values.

```
first_name = 'Ross'
last_name = 'Taylor'
```

In order to print out what you send via inputs, you need to use the parameters to form the string.

Essentially the two lines above are the problem, as they always populate the sting.

try the following:

```
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    # Create a string using the method parameter values
    result = f'Hello {first_name} {last_name} ! You are welcome.'
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Assign a value to first_name
    first_name = input('first_name: ')
    # Assign a value to last_name
    last_name = input('last_name: ')
    # Call the method passing in the values set above
    print_full_name(first_name, last_name)
```